Why is charge parity (eigenvalue of $\hat{C}$) conserved?
Looking at processes with neutral initial and final state, for example
$$e^+e^- \rightarrow \gamma \gamma$$
we know that charge parity (eigenvalue of charge conjugation operator $\hat{C}$) is conserved.
Often it is said that is because the universe is symmetric under charge conjugation, which means that given any physical process, the same process can happen if we exchange every particle with its antiparticle.
But i cannot understand how we can conclude charge parity conservation from charge conjugation symmetry, since those are two different statements.
Why isn't it possible to have a universe which is symmetric under charge conjugation but where charge parity isn't conserved?

Do you simply mean charge is conserved?
If you mean charge conjugation together with parity as in the "CPT theorem", then that actually need not be conserved. (Only when combined with time reversal, so your question could also be changed into "why does the CPT theorem hold?" Please clarify...)

The question is then rather why does 'CPT theorem' imply conservation of charge parity/ parity. By charge parity i mean the eigenvalue of the charge conjugation operator.

? Charge parity is not Charge conjugation for you?

By Charge Parity being conserved I mean the eigenvalue of the charge conjugation operator being conserved.
